# Error running Grails 3.0.7 commands after installing with SDKman

Tags: grails, sdkman

I have installed Grails 3.0.7 via sdkman and I am facing quite weird issues:

1. when I run `grails -h` in console I can see only 3 available commands
2. when I run a Grails command not in the list of available command I get an NPE. For example, `grails generate-all` or `grails run-app` fail.

What can be wrong? Has anyone else encountered this?

Comment: I just installed Grails with sdkman on Windows 7 and cygwin and I am not seeing these issues.  What operating system are you on? What version of java is installed?

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 15.04 and Java 1.8_60

Comment: same java version on gentoo i get outside of a grails project still the same help page (basically only `create`) and inside a project when i use `generate-all` it fails for being a not supported command and `run-all` works as expected. you might want to check with `which grails` and `sdk u grails` if everything is in order and on the right version